# BMI Calculator in C, Undeclared Identifiers

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a BMI calculator. I'm getting multiple "undeclared identifier" errors even though I've made them?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{//main method

    //Ex 2.32
    printf("Ex 2.32: Body Mass Index Calculator\n\n");

    int weightInPounds;
    int heightInInches;
    int bmi;

    //displays title
    printf("Body Mass Index Calculator\n");

    //user input for weight
    printf("Please input your weight in pounds:\n");
    scanf("%d", &weightInPounds);

    //user input for height
    printf("Please input your height in inches:\n");
    scanf("%d", &heightInInches);

    //caluclate BMI
    bmi = (weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches*heightInInches);
    printf("\n");   

    //display BMI categories
    printf("BMI Values\n");
    printf("Underweight: less than 18.5\n");
    printf("Normal: between 18.5 and 24.9\n");
    printf("Overweight: between 25 and 29.9\n");
    printf("Obese: 30 or greater\n\n");

    //display user BMI
    printf("Your BMI is: %d", &bmi);
    //end Ex 2.32

}//end main function
```

Comment: In c89 all variable declarations must occur at the start of a block. Perhaps your compiler is enforcing that? Can you paste the full errors?

Comment: OT: `printf("Your BMI is: %d", &bmi);` must be `printf("Your BMI is: %d", bmi);`

Comment: @FatalError, you should upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: What happens when you move the first `printf` statement to the point right after the variable declarations?  If you're using an older compiler, that will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine ! There are errors in the code such as :

```
printf("Your BMI is: %d", &bmi);
```

You just have to print it like this :

```
printf("Your BMI is: %d", bmi);
```

Comment: You should post that as a comment, it's not an answer

Comment: accepted and downvote undone. But maybe you should explain taht in the answer itself. Head up only 28 rep to go :-)

Comment: @Nicolas Are you suggesting using scanf without an address operator `&` when reading to integers?!

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is old, it wants you to do something that is not really wrong, just how it was programmed some years ago.

Also you have a problem with your code: 
`printf("Your BMI is: %d", &bmi);`

Change it to:

```
printf("Your BMI is: %d", bmi);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information you've given, the most likely candidate is that your compiler is enforcing a C89 rule that requires all variable declarations to be placed at the start of a block. Take the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("Welcome to my program\n");

  int x = 5;
  printf("x = %d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

I can make `gcc` extra picky:

```
$ gcc -pedantic-errors -std=c89 -c vars.c
vars.c: In function ‘main’:
vars.c:7:3: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
```

To fix this error, the variable declaration must be raised to the top of the block:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x = 5;

  printf("Welcome to my program\n");
  printf("x = %d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

And now it will build just fine that way. The fact that you see this behavior by default likely means you're using an old compiler (or possibly something specialized that only supports c89).